# Inner join mysql?

Tags: mysql

This is my inner join, it doesnt appear to work, is there anything wrong with the syntax?

```
$db->query("SELECT name FROM stockists INNER JOIN shops ON stockists.name = shops.name");
```

Comment: Try
    $db->query("SELECT name FROM stockists INNER JOIN shops ON(stockists.name = shops.name);");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT s.`name` FROM stockists st INNER JOIN shops s ON st.`name`= s.`name`
```

Execute....

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
SELECT shops.name
```

the column **`name`** is ambiguous, exist in both tables (shops and stockists)

like `"SELECT shops.name FROM stockists INNER JOIN shops ON stockists.name = shops.name"`

read on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql-error-1052/info)

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
$db->query("SELECT name FROM stockists INNER JOIN shops ON stockists.name = shops.name");
```

The problem here is that you should specify *which* name you would like to have :

```
$db->query("SELECT stockists.name FROM stockists INNER JOIN shops ON stockists.name = shops.name");
```

or

```
$db->query("SELECT shops.name FROM stockists INNER JOIN shops ON stockists.name = shops.name");
```